# Message exchange between different instances of my android application

Tags: android, chat, messaging

I would like to create an Android application that neeeds to communicate with same application at a different device from different users. The user will be logged into the application using his Google+ account and he will be able to exchange messages with his friends. Imagine it like a chat application without a server in the middle. 
The problem is that I don't own a server so the communication must be based to any Google framework or it must be implemented from device to device.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe its possible to connect two devices over the internet without a server somewhere in the middle, basically there is no practical way for the devices to find each other without some known location they can both contact.

Your server wouldn't need to be too complex/expensive for  testing usage. The free tier of Google Apps Engine, or a $5 PHP hosting account should do it.